# Tableau LOD question (How to use percent of total ignoring one filter but keep other filters?)

Tags: tableau-api

One question here is that How can we use percent of total ignoring filter A but keep filter B?

For example, this chart, I would like the label shows percent of total of all countries, even though I choose top 14 countries. Meanwhile, I want Filter Edition works.

Now, I am using the formula:{ FIXED  [Country] :SUM ([Filter(Metrics_Summary)])/SUM({SUM([Filter(Metrics_Summary)])})}
in this way, the number shows percent of total ignoring country filter, however, when I click edition, this filter doesn't work

If I want percent of total ignoring country filter but keep edition filter. What should I do?

Thanks everyone!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCEnN.png)

Answer (score 2):

Put the Edition filter to context. Right-click on the filter; Add to Context.